# durandaljs - weyland building in bat file

Tags: durandal-2.0, weyland

I'm a little confused about something. I'm trying to use weyland to do a build and am having some issues adding weyland build to bat file.
It seems like after weyland executes... it tells me it created the main-built.js file however, the script stops immediately.

I have a few commands I want to execute after weyland builds and doesn't work - any ideas?

Calling it using "weyland build"

I think my config is pretty vanilla...  any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
exports.config = function(weyland) {
    weyland.build('main')
        .task.jshint({
            include: 'app/**/*.js',
            exclude: 'app/main-built.js'
        })
        .task.uglifyjs({
            include:['app/**/*.js', 'lib/durandal/**/*.js']
        })
        .task.rjs({
            include:['app/**/*.{js,html}', 'lib/durandal/**/*.js'],
            loaderPluginExtensionMaps:{
                '.html':'text'
            },
            rjs:{
                name: '../lib/require/almond-custom', //to deploy with require.js, use the build's name here instead
                insertRequire:['main'], //not needed for require
                baseUrl: 'app',
                wrap:true, //not needed for require
                paths : {
                    'text': '../lib/require/text',
                    'durandal': '../lib/durandal/js',
                    'plugins': '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
                    'transitions': '../lib/durandal/js/transitions'
                    //'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0'
                    //'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
                    //'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1'
                },
                inlineText: true,
                optimize : 'none',
                pragmas: {
                    build: true
                },
                stubModules : ['text'],
                keepBuildDir: true,
                out:'app/main-built.js'
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install node.js and then weyland, once you have done that you could run weyland build from  node command prompt (or as post build task in Visual Studio)
Refer this page: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Building-with-Weyland/

Comment: I did that already... i'm running a bat script that executes weyland build. It works, but the problem is it stops execution ... afterwards i have other things that need to happen, copying to staging server etc.